# Create zip file using log4j2 weekly basis

Tags: java, log4j2

I am using log4j2 for logging user activities in a text file. Now I want to create a zip file of user activity. But I want this way. I create a text file of everyday user log activity. So I have seven text file of 7 days. After seven days when 8th-day text file create the first-day text file should convert in a zip file. So expected behavior like this 1st-day text file should in a zip file and other 2nd to 8th-day file in text format when 8th-day text file creates.

========================================================================

I used this which I saw you my code.
[image: code for log4j2]

Actual Result getting like this.

```
1. dhiren-audit-2019-07-22.log / text file
2. dhiren-audit-2019-07-23.log / text file
3. dhiren-audit-2019-07-24.log / text file
4. dhiren-audit-2019-07-25.log / text file
5. dhiren-audit-2019-07-26.log / text file
6. dhiren-audit-2019-07-27.log / text file
7. dhiren-audit-2019-07-28.log / text file
8. dhiren-audit-2019-07-29.log / text file
```

But Expected / I want result like this.

```
1. dhiren-audit-2019-07-22.log.gz / Zip file
2. dhiren-audit-2019-07-23.log / text file
3. dhiren-audit-2019-07-24.log / text file
4. dhiren-audit-2019-07-25.log / text file
5. dhiren-audit-2019-07-26.log / text file
6. dhiren-audit-2019-07-27.log / text file
7. dhiren-audit-2019-07-28.log / text file
8. dhiren-audit-2019-07-29.log / text file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rolling file appender to ensure a new log file is used everyday. With respect to converting older log files as zip - not sure if logging framework provides it but this can be easily accomplished by a scheduled job

Answer (score 0):

In general, I prefer log4j2 to decide about rolling. Regarding to the archiving or backing up the logs, I am taking advantages of batch scripting and cron features of operating systems.

Log4j2 provides rich adjustments for rolling the logs. The manual page includes detailed statements and examples. It would be wise to check the manual page.

I think you can achieve what you need by starting with the examples which I quoted from the manual page:

> Below is a sample configuration that uses a RollingFileAppender with
>   both the time and size based triggering policies, will create up to 7
>   archives on the same day (1-7) that are stored in a directory based on
>   the current year and month, and will compress each archive using gzip:
>
> ```
> Sample configuration XML
> ```
>
> Below is a sample configuration that uses a RollingFileAppender with
>   both the time and size based triggering policies, will create up to 7
>   archives on the same day (1-7) that are stored in a directory based on
>   the current year and month, and will compress each archive using gzip
>   and will roll every 6 hours when the hour is divisible by 6:
>
> ```
> Sample configuration XML
> ```

Please take a look at the page: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RolloverStrategies